# Keep text and menu inside div tag?

Tags: html, text, menu, tags

I can't get my menu and my text to stay inside the div tags?

Can someo one help me?

www.sverkel.dk/index3.php

```css
    body {
     margin: 0;
     font-family:verdana;
    }
    
    
    header {
     background: #cf5858; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cf5858 0%, #902727 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cf5858), color-stop(100%,#902727)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* W3C */
    }
    
    #btn-menu {
     display: none;   
    }
    
    header label {
     display:none;
     width: 30px;
     height:20px;
     padding:10px;
     border-right:1px solid #fff;
    }
    
    
    header label:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .menu ul {
     margin:0;
     list-style:none;
     padding:0;
     display:flex;
     justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .menu li {
    }
    
    .menu li:hover {
     background:#9E3C3E;
    }
    
    .menu li a {
     display: block;
     padding: 15px 20px;
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    main {
     padding:20px;
    }
    
    @media (max-width:768px) {
     header label {
      display:block;
     }
     
     .menu {
      position:absolute;
      background: #cf5858; /* Old browsers */
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cf5858 0%, #902727 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cf5858), color-stop(100%,#902727)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* IE10+ */
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cf5858 0%,#902727 100%); /* W3C */
      width:70%;
      margin-left: -70%;
      transition: all 0.3s;
     }
     
     .menu ul {
      flex-direction:column;
     }
     
     .menu li {
      border-top: 1px solid #fff;
     }
     
     #btn-menu:checked ~ .menu {
      margin:0;
     }
     
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top" id="cell1"></div>
    
    <div class="midt" id="cell2">    
    <header>
        <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
        <label for="btn-menu"><img src="billeder/menux.png"></label>
    
        <nav class="menu">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Forside</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produkter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Priser</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Om os</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
       </ul>
       </nav>
    </header>
    </div>
        
        
    <div class="indhold" id="cell3" align="center"><br><h2>Velkommen til vores nye hjemmeside</h2><br><br>Her på siden vil du finde en masse informationer om vores services, produkter, priser og meget andet. Siden er stadig under opbygning...</div>
        
    <div class="bund" id="cell4"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: please post your code here rather than asking people to visit a URL

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: You have no width defined any where, you could add 
`.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 880px;
}` to center it and set a width.

Comment: I've modified your question to include the html and css, so you don't need to add them to the comments.

Comment: I got that to work, perfect! But how can I get the red menu "inside" the grey box? I just need 1 mm on both sides? 

Also, now the site won't scale?